# How to select pagination wise N number of records from MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

In one of my recent PHP (CodeIgniter) based projects, a MySQL table contains almost 30.000 records (and will increase more). If I show those records as a list, the performance is reduced (MySQL retrieves all of those records in a quick time, but running a PHP loop for around 30.000 times is not feasible). So my plan is to load 100 records at a time and create a pagination so that the user can select a page number to load that specified number of records.

I can load the first 100 records easily using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100
```

But the problem is: when I select `page=2, page=3, ...., page=n`. How can I write a MySQL query that will load 2nd 100 records (for page=2), 3rd 100 records (for page=3),... ... nth 100 record (for page=n)?

**N.B:** Please refer the 101 number record may not have the id 101, similar 201 number record may not have the id of 201, so please don't suggest me a query that will depend on **Primary Key**

Can anyone help me to find out the correct query?

- Thanks

Comment: You can use the mysql limit offset.. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: general approach would be `SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT (<pageNumber> - 1) * <numRows>, <numRows>`

Comment: Just a side question.. Is it the best design to call your database each time you advance in your page, or to load the whole database at first and then displaying only X element per page??

I don't have the answer, it is a serious question

Comment: @Shimul check this to handle pagination https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/.
Once you are done with this pagination its just a matter of posting page number to php script and then generate sql query accordingly i mean the offset value.

Comment: @LilianBarraud if you fetch the whole table content at once and navigate through the recordset, you won't be able to see the newly added data. not to mention the cost and the question of where and how you'll be storing those records.

Answer (score 4):

first hundred

```
 SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 100
```

next hundred

```
 SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100, 100
```

you're very observant about putting the order by in

**THE LIMIT STATEMENT EXPLAINED:**
*The `LIMIT` statement is NOT a `WHERE` clause. It does not select by `id` nor in fact by any criteria, (there `where` clause does that) Instead the `limit` clause simply ensures that you are returned a piece of the `block` of results that are subset of "everything". Hence why it is important to mention an `order by` each time, so that each subsequent call will give you the correct piece of the data block in order, and you can 'next', 'next', 'next' through them*

EG: for the disordered table `this_table`:

```
+-------+-------------+
|  id   |   value     |
+-------+-------------+
|  1    |     bob     |
|  12   |     fish    |
|  112  |     pink    |
|  2    |     cat     |
|  8    |     dog     |
|  56   |     blue    |
|  88   |     grey    |
|  87   |     red     |
+-------+-------------+
```

the selects return as below:

```
SELECT * FROM <this_table> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,5
+-------+-------------+
|  id   |   value     |
+-------+-------------+
|  1    |     bob     |
|  2    |     cat     |
|  8    |     dog     |
|  12   |     fish    |
|  56   |     blue    |
+-------+-------------+
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM <this_table> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5,5
+-------+-------------+
|  id   |   value     |
+-------+-------------+
|  87   |     red     |
|  88   |     grey    |
|  112  |     pink    |
+-------+-------------+
```

notice the lack of rows 9 and 10 this is deliberate and shows MySQL working as intended

incidentally you should also look at adding an index on `id` this will MASSIVELY increase the speed of these selects

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD INDEX `id` (`id`)
```

Comment: For the second page (it starts from 101 to next 100), what if there is no data having id 101? I mean after id = 100, next id starts from 107 or 120, then?

Comment: you're misunderstanding it --> `limit 0,100` gives you FROM 0-> TO 99 INCLUSIVE --> `limit 100, 100` gives you FROM 100-> TO 199 INCLUSIVE --> `limit 200, 100` gives you FROM 200-> TO 299 INCLUSIVE

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT <p * 100>, 100
```

so u must have

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 100
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100, 100
```

this work if first page = 0, else, u need (p-1) * 100

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: For the second page (it starts from 101 to next 100), what if there is no data having id 101? I mean after id = 100, next id starts from 107 or 120, then?

Comment: 107, 120, 137 ...  etc. You just cut data how u want