# SQL lazy load - SELECT a range but discard previously selected entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a set of `brochure` objects that have different `language` versions, stored in my database. A `brochure` will share a `doc_id` across all of its own versions. Here's what my db looks like:

```
 ___________________________________________________
|   id   |   doc_id   |   language   |   etc...     |
|    1   |  628fdd40  |      en      |              |
|    2   |  628fdd40  |      fr      |              |
|    3   |  0ba86e5b  |      en      |              |
|    4   |  628fdd40  |      jp      |              |
 etc...
```

I want to lazy load these brochures as they are required, using a query similar to

```
SELECT * FROM Brochures
WHERE (id BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
```

but I don't want to select any brochures twice - ie if I have selected a French version I don't want to also select the English, Japanese etc versions. I can't guarantee that the brochures will have been entered into the database sequentially (as demonstrated in the DB example above)

I thought of using a `NOT IN` clause to filter out the previously selected `doc_id`'s but that would require me to keep an ever-increasing list of `doc_id`'s somewhere, most likely in the `$_SESSION`, or passing that swelling list via my AJAX requests. That doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

I also thought maybe I could run another table that keeps track of the previously selected `doc_id`'s against sessions by running an `UPDATE` after each selection is made and then sub-querying the `NOT IN` clause. I'm not sure of the implications there.

Is there something clever I can do here? Has anyone come up with something similar? Does this even make sense?

Comment: use a `group by` doc_id but you need to have a function for the language (say) `max(language)` EG: `SELECT MAX(language) FROM Brochures
WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 20 GROUP BY doc_id` either that or do a subselect if you need more than one field you could also just run a NORMAL select and simply `limit 0,1` at the end EG: `SELECT * FROM Brochures WHERE (id BETWEEN 10 AND 20) LIMIT 0,1` and you can add a `AND doc_id NOT IN()` to ignore previously selected

Comment: When do you need the brochure object? Is there some click event when you would be able to get a single one, or should all be avaidable at once with all information?

Comment: @MrHeelis using the `GROUP BY` would help in filtering out duplicate languages per query, but what if two separate queries requesting different ranges hold the same `doc_id`? I'd still have to save that state somewhere

Comment: @H.J.Meijer I'm loading them in as the user scrolls the page, so I want to request a range as I go. I could request them individually but that would result in periodically shooting off fifty AJAX requests at once, and handling the results

Comment: Yes, in that case, individual requests don't make sense. Do you limit yourself to one language per session? Would it be possible to load the English and Japanese version of the same doc_id?

Comment: Not all brochures have all languages, so I am selecting the preferred language first, and if that doesn't exist I select the default language version instead. Default language is set by the client at some point. The language switching is handled by my php class once the results are returned

Answer (score 0):

Having re-read the question and seen your comments I can now state categorically you are not using MySQL properly. You have assumed you need to use the `WHERE (id= range)` to achieve pagination. This is incorrect you need to use the specific tools in MySQL to get PAGINATION. (what you called lazy loading)

```
 SELECT * FROM Brochures ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,10
 SELECT * FROM Brochures ORDER BY id LIMIT 10,10
 SELECT * FROM Brochures ORDER BY id LIMIT 20,10
```

This mechanic achieves this - it is trivial to add `WHERE` clauses to this.

this will mean you get ten records at a time, simply selecting with specificity - using `WHERE distinct` or `group by`

I appreciate this has steepened the learning curve for you somewhat but this is the task. This is how to do it, I am right . Good luck. make sure you use `order by id`

PS: I would recommend adding an index on `id` when you use the order by in your pagination.

PPS: [I recently explained to another SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694330/how-to-select-pagination-wise-n-number-of-records-from-mysql-database/49694374?noredirect=1#comment86466221_49694374) how they too had got the role of the `where` clause muddled up with the role of `limit` this in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first occurrence of a brochure by using a query like this:

```
select b.*
from brochures b
where b.id = (select min(b2.id) from brochures b2 where b2.doc_id = b.doc_id)
order by id;
```

For performance, you want an index on `brochures(doc_id, id)`.

That said, your query will work in practice.  However, SQL and MySQL do not guarantee the ordering of the result set unless you include an `ORDER BY` for the outermost `SELECT`.  You should include the `ORDER BY` so your code is resilient (for instance, changing databases or swapping view for the table might do unexpected things).

Comment: the clue to this chaps mis-comprehension of this issue is how he's using `where id=between`.. if you read between the lines you can see that he's started out wrongly